# REST API Concepts

Tags: rest, http, web

I'm trying to grasp the essence of REST API and i have some questions that i'd be happy if someone could clarify:

**First**

From Wikipedia:

> it is a network of Web resources (a virtual state-machine) where the user progresses through the application by selecting resource identifiers such as http://www.example.com/articles/21 and resource operations such as GET or POST (application state transitions), resulting in the next resource's representation (the next application state) being transferred to the end user for their use.

What is the meaning of "application state"? As far as i understand, an application that exposes a REST API is stateless, so it doesn't have a "state" by definition? It just replies to client requests, which contain all the information needed by the server to respond to those requests. In other words, it doesn't hold any context. Am i correct?

**Second** 
One of the 6 constraints is **client-server** architecture. Why is that a constraint? isn't it correct that every API is in a client-server architecture? eventually, API is  Application Programming **Interface**. ??

**Third**

[from here](https://dzone.com/articles/5-easy-to-spot-tells-that-your-rest-api-is-not-res):

> Using generic media types such as JSON is fundamentally not RESTful because REST requires the messages to be self-descriptive. Self-descriptiveness just means that the semantics of the data should travel with the data itself.

What is the original meaning behind the self-descriptiveness constraint, and does using a generic media-type violate this constraint?

**Fourth** 
I've seen in many places that REST is not HTTP, and doesn't have to use HTTP as it's undelying protocol, it's just natural to use HTTP because the set of methods it has (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE). Can someone explain why is it natural for REST and give an example for another way to use REST other then HTTP?

Comment: _” I've seen in many places that REST is not HTTP”_ Out of curiosity, what places? What else is used instead?

Comment: Some word of warning in regards to Wikipedia entries about REST by [Fielding himself](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven#comment-724). Later on he was asked in an interview why he didn't fix the article then and he just responded as this would make him the only one to decide whether something is RESTful or not among other factors.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as i understand, an application that exposes a REST API is stateless, so it doesn't have a "state" by definition?

No, the communication itself should be stateless. REST is an abbreviation for *REpresentational State Transfer*, so the term state is even included in the name itself.

It is probably easier to think here in terms of traditional Web pages. If you have a server that keeps client state in it, i.e. manages multiple clients sessions, what you end up is having a scaling issue sooner or later. You can't add a further server the client can connect to to retrieve the same information as the session is tide to the server it was communicating before. One might try to share the server state through a remote bus (i.e. Redis queues or the like) but this leads to plenty other challenges that are not easily solvable.

In the words of Fielding:

> REST is software design on the scale of decades: every detail is intended to promote software longevity and independent evolution. Many of the constraints are directly opposed to short-term efficiency. Unfortunately, people are fairly good at short-term design, and usually awful at long-term design. Most don’t think they need to design past the current release. ([Source](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven#comment-724))

In my sense statelessness is less a constraint on independent evolution than it is on system scalability though. If you just take client-server decoupling into account, based on content type negotiation, usage of HATEOAS and so on, statelessness is not really a blocker here, though it takes a way a lot of background complexities if you avoid sharing client state, i.e. its current session data, across your server landscape.

> One of the 6 constraints is client-server architecture. Why is that a constraint? isn't it correct that every API is in a client-server architecture? eventually, API is Application Programming Interface. ??

What are the counterparts to client-server architectures? Applications that don't have to deal with other applications. If an application does not have to communicate with other applications you don't need to be that careful in your design for it having to adapt to changes or avoid any coupling between its components as it is always treated as one thing. As quoted above, *REST is software design on the scale of decades*. As such, the same services you put online should still work in years to come and in essence should have the freedom to evolve in future.

Interoperability is one of the core issues in client-server architectures. If two participants do not talk the same language or do have a different understanding of the domain, they will have a hard time communicating with each other. Just put a Chinese and a Frenchmen in the same room and watch them try to solve a particular issue. Unless they do understand a minimal language set, i.e. English, communication will be the main problem to solve that issue.

> What is the original meaning behind the self-descriptiveness constraint, and does using a generic media-type violate this constraint?

I start by quoting this statement from an actually good blog post:

> A self-descriptive message is one that contains all the information that the recipient needs to understand it. There should not be additional information in a separate documentation or in another message. ([Source](https://codewords.recurse.com/issues/five/what-restful-actually-means))

If you now take a closer look at the [JSON spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) It just defines the basic syntax but does not define any semantics. So, in essence you know that objects start and end with curly braces (`{`, `}`), that an object consists of a set of key and values where the key is a string value and the value may either be a string, a number, a boolean, a further object or an array and so on. But it doesn't tell you anything about the actual structure, which elements are shipped within a document and so on. XML i.e. has document type definitions (DTDs) and XML schemas that define which elements and attributes are in which order and what their admissible values are and the like. While [JSON (Hyper-)Schema](https://json-schema.org/) attempts to fill this gap, it still doesn't define the semantics of the fields fully, i.e. in which context which elements may appear and what not. JSON itself also lacks support for URLs/URIs and JSON hyper-schema now tries to add support for it at least.

If you take a look at HTML i.e., the spec has already gone through different versions now but it was designed with backward compatibility in mind and even in version 5 you can use the tags defined in the original version and browser will be able to handle your Web page more or less correctly. A further part of self-descriptiveness comes through HTML's [form support](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html). A server can thereby teach a client not only on the data elements of a resource, i.e. about field name expecting a text input whereas a time field presents you a calendar widget to select a specific date and time entry and so on, but it will also tell a client the URI where to send the request to, which HTTP operation to use and which media-type to use to send the request in. While this already tackles HATEOAS as well, a client understanding HTML will know what the server wants it to do and therefore does not need to consult any external documentation that describes how a request should look like.

HTML is in essence a generic media type. You can use it to depict details of a specific car model but also to show news and other data. A media type in the end is nothing more than a human-readable definition how an application (client or server) should process data that is said to be of that format. As such, a generic media type is preferable to specific ones as it allows and promotes the reusage of that media type for many other domains and those increase the likelihood of its support across different vendors.

> I've seen in many places that REST is not HTTP, and doesn't have to use HTTP as it's undelying protocol, it's just natural to use HTTP because the set of methods it has (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE). Can someone explain why is it natural for REST and give an example for another way to use REST other then HTTP?

As "Uncle Bob" Martin stated [architecture is about intent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_TH-Y78tt4&t=860s). As already quoted above, REST is all about decoupling clients from servers to allow servers to evolve freely in future and clients to adopt to changes easily. This is, what basically allowed the Web to grow to its todays size. Fielding just took the concepts used successfully on the Web, mostly by us humans, and started questioning why applications do not use our style of interacting with the Web also. Therefore, loosely speaking, REST is just Web surfing for applications.

REST itself is just an architectural style. Like some churches use a gothic style, others a modern one and yet other a baroque one, each style has its unique properties that differentiate it from the others. In software engineering you have also a couple of different styles you can follow, such as monolithic or n-tier architectures, MVC architecture, domain specific languages (DSLs), SOA, peer-to-peer architectures, cloud computing (serverless, ...) and so on. Each of these have their own characteristics and unique proposition features, benefits and drawbacks. As in traditional architecture you can mix and match different styles into one approach, though the final result may not be what you were initially aiming for and remember, each style attempts to tackle at least one major concern.

Fielding was working on the HTTP 1.0 and 1.1 specification (among others) and analyzed the architecture of the Web in this doctoral thesis. Therefore it is no miracle in my sense that REST does work well on top of HTTP, but as already mentioned, he might have taken a to-close look at HTTP and the Web as statelessness is, at least in my understanding, less a concern for future evolution than for scalability. While scalability might be a future concern as well, I wouldn't call it a high-priority constraint in that regard, even though Fielding claims that all of the constraints are mandatory to deserve the REST tag.

As such, REST itself does not tie you to HTTP as it is just an architectural style. It does not forbid to deviate from its core ideas, but you might miss out on some of the properties it advocates (besides misusing the term REST eventually). But as REST goes almost hand in hand with HTTP, it is like the perfect match and why change it?! Sure, you could come up with a new transport protocol in future and apply the same concepts used to interact with Web pages to that protocol and you will more or less end with a REST architecture. Your protocol however should at least support URIs, media-types, link-relations and [content-type negotiation](https://www.w3.org/blog/2006/02/content-negotiation/). These are the foundation blocks IMO that every REST enabled application needs to support, as these guarantee the exchange of well-defined messages and the ability to act upon these.

As [HTTP is just a transport protocol](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=191s) to transfer a document from a source machine to a target, one might question why SMTP, FTP or similar protocols are not used for REST architectures as well. While these protocols also transfer documents from one point to an other, they either lack support for media-types (S/FTP/S) or do not support the uniform interface constraint fully, i.e. by not supporting HATEOAS fully and the like. Besides that, both require a particular login to create a session which may or not be seen as violation of the statelessness constraint.